# How to multiply tensors in MATLAB without looping?

Tags: performance, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization, multiplication

Suppose I have:

```
A = rand(1,10,3);
B = rand(10,16);
```

And I want to get:

```
C(:,1) = A(:,:,1)*B;
C(:,2) = A(:,:,2)*B;
C(:,3) = A(:,:,3)*B;
```

Can I somehow multiply this in a single line so that it is faster?

What if I create new tensor b like this

```
for i = 1:3
    b(:,:,i) = B;
end
```

Can I multiply A and b to get the same C but faster? Time taken in creation of b by the loop above doesn't matter since I will be needing C for many different A-s while B stays the same.

Comment: What if `A = rand(4,10,3)`, that is a `3D` array without singleton dimensions? What must be the output then?

Comment: @Divakar It's always singleton in my problem.

Comment: In that case, just `squeeze` `A` and use matrix multiplication - `C = B.'*squeeze(A)`.

Comment: @Divakar That's what LuisMendo answered and it did speed up the program, thank you anyways!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Permute the dimensions of `A` and `B` and then apply matrix multiplication:

```
C = B.'*permute(A, [2 3 1]);
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. However, the OP should keep in mind that this solution only works because the first dimension of A is singleton.

Comment: 10% execution time reduction! Thank you so much!

Comment: Very nice, but I wonder why OP is using a 3 dimensional array with a singleton dimension

Answer (score 6):

If `A` is a *true* 3D array, something like `A = rand(4,10,3)` and assuming that `B` stays as a 2D array, then each `A(:,:,1)*B` would yield a 2D array.

So, assuming that you want to store those 2D arrays as slices in the third dimension of output array, `C` like so -

```
C(:,:,1) = A(:,:,1)*B;
C(:,:,2) = A(:,:,2)*B;
C(:,:,3) = A(:,:,3)*B; and so on.
```

To solve this in a vectorized manner, one of the approaches would be to use reshape `A` into a 2D array merging the first and third dimensions and then performing matrix-muliplication. Finally, to bring the output size same as the earlier listed `C`, we need a final step of reshaping.

The implementation would look something like this -

```
%// Get size and then the final output C
[m,n,r] = size(A);
out = permute(reshape(reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),[],n)*B,m,r,[]),[1 3 2]);
```

Sample run -

```
>> A = rand(4,10,3);
B = rand(10,16);

C(:,:,1) = A(:,:,1)*B;
C(:,:,2) = A(:,:,2)*B;
C(:,:,3) = A(:,:,3)*B;
>> [m,n,r] = size(A);
out = permute(reshape(reshape(permute(A,[1 3 2]),[],n)*B,m,r,[]),[1 3 2]);
>> all(C(:)==out(:)) %// Verify results
ans =
     1
```

---

As per the [`comments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497176/how-to-multiply-tensors-in-matlab-without-looping#comment50962569_31497176), if `A` is a 3D array with always a singleton dimension at the start, you can just use [`squeeze`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) and then matrix-multiplication like so -

```
C = B.'*squeeze(A)
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** @LuisMendo points out that this is indeed possible for this specific use case. However, it is not (in general) possible if the first dimension of A is not 1.

I've grappled with this for a while now, and I've never been able to come up with a solution. Performing element-wise calculations is made nice by `bsxfun`, but tensor multiplication is something which is woefully unsupported.  Sorry, and good luck!

You can check out [this mathworks file exchange file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16275-tprod-arbitary-tensor-products-between-n-d-arrays), which will make it easier for you and supports the behavior you're looking for, but I believe that it relies on loops as well. **Edit**: it relies on MEX/C++, so it isn't a pure MATLAB solution if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You're correct, I've updated my answer. I'll leave it here to point out that, in general, your solution does not hold. However, it does indeed solve the question posed here.

Comment: I've removed my downvote after your edit. It's not clear to me that tensor multiplication is what the OP is after, though. If the first dimension of  `A` where not `1`, the assignment `C(:,1) = A(:,:,1)*B` in the question wouldn't make sense, because `A(:,:,1)*B` would be a matrix, not a vector

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with @GJSein, the for loop is really fast

```
time
    0.7050    0.3145
```

Here's the timer function

```
function time

    n = 1E7;
    A = rand(1,n,3);
    B = rand(n,16);
    t = [];
    C = {};

    tic
        C{length(C)+1} = squeeze(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x*B,num2cell(A,[1 2]),'UniformOutput',false)));
    t(length(t)+1) = toc;

    tic
        for i = 1:size(A,3)
            C{length(C)+1}(:,i) = A(:,:,i)*B;
        end
    t(length(t)+1) = toc;

    disp(t)
end
```